# How to resize imageicon with same quality

Tags: java, resize, imageicon

I`m currently making an application to manage other application on windows.

when i resize the icon it change quality

i`m getting icon by this code

`ShellFolder shell = ShellFolder.getShellFolder(new File(load1.getString("Path"))); 
image = shell.getIcon(true);`

And when i resize it it change the quality.
My resize code is

`sIMG = image.getScaledInstance(45, 45, Image.SCALE_AREA_AVERAGING);`

What i want to do to keep the quality of the icon.

Please help.

Comment: Are you asking how to not lose image quality for an icon if you alter the size ?

Comment: It's kind of hard to guess what you really want to achieve here, but as you are using the `ShellFolder` class, I guess you want the native OS' icons. Unfortunately, the `ShellFolder` class only gives you either 16x16 or 32x32 ("large") images. To get larger icons you will need some kind of native integration. I would think such a library already exists, if not, it should be rather simple to write a quick interface using JNA.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you want to re-size your icon to look the same no matter what size you change it to. Regular images will are composed of pixels therefore lost of quality is inevitable.

When I did a web design project at my school I learned about Vector images(.svg). 
**Summary Of Vector Vs Bitmap** http://etc.usf.edu/techease/win/images/what-is-the-difference-between-bitmap-and-vector-images/

Of course anyone please correct me if I'm wrong but I think vectors is the only way you can achieve your goal assuming that I'm understanding your question. Vector image quality does not change much or at all on re-size.

Java doesn't natively support Vector Images but follow this tutorial and you should achieve your goal. (It's not really a tutorial more like copy and paste)

http://plindenbaum.blogspot.com/2009/07/simple-java-based-svg-renderer.html

Also this link will let you convert your existing images to SVG

http://vectormagic.com/home

(you get 2 downloads when you sign up) There are other tools to convert to SVG but this was the quickest solution I could find. If you're good with Photoshop I think I saw some tutorials for it but don't quote me on that.
I hope this is what you were looking for best of luck to.

Comment: is there any way i can use this for my Stand alone application?

Comment: http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/

Using this toolkit you should be able to.

Also found this tutorial for it, it seems simpler than the documentation give it a try and report back. 

http://bbgen.net/blog/2011/06/java-svg-to-bufferedimage/

Comment: can you post your attempt? 
Also can you post a link if possible to the icon you are trying to re-size? One thing that I could also tell you that may make your job easier is that if you can find the same image except bigger it would take a lot of the stress away. Quality is not lost as it shrinks. It may be more beneficial to use a bigger image and go smaller than vise versa.

Answer (score -2):

you can resize any image by the following code.

```
$thumb = new Imagick();
$thumb->readImage('myimage.gif');    $thumb->resizeImage(320,240,Imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS,1);
$thumb->writeImage('mythumb.gif');
$thumb->clear();
$thumb->destroy();
```

For more information please go to the following link.

[resize image](http://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.resizeimage.php)

[resize optimized image](http://explorephpcodes.blogspot.in/2014/05/resize-image-by-php-script.html)

Comment: so sorry you can use the following link to see the java resize the imags http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-resize-an-image-in-java/

Comment: @quicksoft I use that method also but i wont solve my problem